# Swift 3 linkedin integration condition if linkedin app already install in iPhone device

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing some problem in linkedin integration in my application. As linkedin app is already install in my iPhone device. but whenever i want to login app through linkedin app its all time move me in AppStore to install linkedin. My question is how to i will check linkedin app is install or not. if linkedin app is already install then i can directly login through linkedin and goto my desired `ViewController`. otherwise i can move user to Appstore to install linkedin app.

In otherhand i used login through WebView. but when i login do not redirect in my desired `ViewController`.

here my code -

```
if statusCode == 200 {

    do {
        let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
        print("response dictionary ::: \(String(describing: dataDictionary!))")

        let accessToken = dataDictionary?["access_token"] as! String


        UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        /*This is the api function from here i go my desired ViewController*/
        self.getProfileInfo ()

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    catch {
        print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
    }
}
```

please give solution for both linkedin login through `WebView` and linkedin app.

Comment: You can try out: https://github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift

Comment: I have already follow this github.com/tonyli508/LinkedinSwift link. but not get solution. Please tell me how to i goto my ViewController after enter emailId and password. And My question second question is how to i will check linkedin app is install or not. if linkedin app is already install then i can directly login through linkedin and goto my desired ViewController. otherwise i can move user to Appstore to install linkedin app.

Comment: Was my code helpful or you need something else?@Rupshikha

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following code and can check with the installation of linkedin with "isInstalled" variable. Change this ,showGoToAppStoreDialog to false to navigate to AppStore if app is not there.

```
   let isInstalled : Bool = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "linkedin://app")!)
   print("\n linkedin app is there:",isInstalled)

   LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
      print("success called!")

      _ = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session

               self.LinkedinLogindetails()

           }) { (error) -> Void in

          if error != nil
          {

          }
           if(self.WebView.isHidden==true)
          {

              self.WebView.isHidden=false
              self.CloseBtn.isHidden=false
          }

              self.linkedinkey = ""
              self.linkedinsecret = ""
              self.authendpoint = "https://www.linikedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"
                        self.accesstokenendpoint = "https://www.linikedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken"
              let redirectURL = "https://com.appcoda.linkedin.oauth/oauth".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)!
              let state = "linkedin\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))"
                        _ = "r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress"
              let url = NSString(format:"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=%@&scope=%@&state=%@&redirect_uri=%@",
                                           self.linkedinkey,"r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress",state,redirectURL)
                   self.Loadurl(url as String)

            }
```